# visual studio 2008 is freezing in design mode

Tags: asp.net, css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

It 's so weird issue :

My visual studio hang up ,consuming 25% CPU and then  I have to use the task manager to shut it down.

This happened when i try to view the `.aspx` of the master page in the `Design view` .

After several attempts :

I has found that removing some references to `css` files fix the problem !!!!  ..

But i want to use those `css` files .I wanna to know how some css files could freeze my visual studio !! ,and how to fix this problem .

Comment: Did you install SP1? It fixes a known issue with HTML design mode slowdowns.

Comment: my version is : `9.0.30729.1 SP`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem too. Installing other programs may replace dlls necessary for the VS to run properly. 
Also, it is always better to avoid the design mode, in my opinion. That is why I use WebMatrix2. But there are sometimes where you REALLY need VS for which there is an integrated button in WebMatrix which opens the same website in VS. Even then, it is possible to completely avoid VS which I have been trying to do.
I suggest you try running the site with WebMatrix to see if it works fine with the css files you deleted.